# notepad++ how to add increase number every end line?

Tags: notepad++

how to add increase number every end line ?

```
study
fly
run
swim
learning
todo
no
```

to become

```
study20978
fly20979
run20980
swim20981
learning20982
todo20983
no20984
```

Comment: are you bound to notepad++ or solution in other tool (e.g. Excel) is also fine?

Comment: OK, please solve to excel solution, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Notepad++ user but I would use free [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) tool for this because it is lean and effective.

[AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) solution (just [download awk.exe](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and run the following command line)

```
awk "BEGIN { c = 20978 }  { print $0 c++ }" input.txt > output.txt
```

Result:

```
study20978
fly20979
run20980
swim20981
learning20982
todo20983
no20984
```

---

**Downloading:**

you do not even need to install the tool, just download and unpack *binaries.zip* and EXE is located in `gawk-3.1.6-1-bin.zip\bin\awk.exe`.

**What the instructions do:**

- `BEGIN { c = 20978 }` we initialized `c` to `20978`. `BEGIN` section runs only once.
- section `{ print $0 c++ }` runs once for each line: we print that line (it is stored in `$0`) and the value of our counter `c` (which we immediately increase: `c++`)

**Making it reusable:**

If you would like to keep the source code for future use, put it to file `numbering.awk` with some nicer formatting:

```
BEGIN { c = 20978 }
{ print $0 c++ }
```

And use modified command line referring to that source file:

```
awk -f numbering.awk input.txt > output.txt
```

You can save this command into `numbering.bat` file so you won't need to rememeber it.

**Additional explanation:**

For your information, less cryptic form of the source would say:

```
# this section runs once at the beginning
BEGIN { c = 20978 }   # initialization of the counter "c"

# this section runs once for each line
{ print $0 c;    # print original line followed by value of counter "c"
  c = c + 1;     # assign value of calculation "c + 1" into "c"
}
```

Comment: i am using windows 10.

cmd.exe says "awk' is nor recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: `awk.exe` is standalone executable so you can copy the `awk.exe` into your working directory so you can see files `input.txt` and `awk.exe` together in one directory.  Then make sure, you are running the command from that directory (if you type `dir` command, it will list `input.txt` and `awk.exe`). If not, type `pushd e:\dir1\dir2` to switch into that path ˛`e:\dir1\dir2` and then it will work.

Comment: @michaelandrew – thank you for letting me know. Also please mark the most useful answer – see [tour].

Answer (score 3):

1. Add some spaces to the last time so that the line becomes the longest.

   [image]
2. Hold Alt+Shift then hit Up Arrows to select an area up to the top of the text.

   [image]
3. Keep holding Alt+Shift then hit Right Arrows to adjust the area so that the cursors are at the end of the lines.

   [image]
4. Hit Alt+C to invoke the Column Editor to add sequence numbers.

   [image]

   [image]
5. Hit Ctrl+H to replace the regular expression `\ +([0-9]+)$` with `$1`

   [image]

   [image]

   Done!

Comment: @BillP3rd – I added awk answer only because the OP [indicated](https://superuser.com/questions/1257801/notepad-how-to-add-increase-number-every-end-line/1257812#comment1849244_1257801) almost from the beginning that N++ is not a strict requirement and this N++ solution has some pitfalls, e.g. "how many spaces is enough to add"? But sure, I am not against it.

Comment: No worries. Just an observation and if tasked with the same, I might well have used AWK. Or VBScript, or maybe even C#. I was, in fact, a little impressed by the N++ solution.